# Create a 2 column table from foreach elements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, foreach

I'm trying to display the results from a foreach iteration in a two column table.
This is my code:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.value
            </td>
       </tr>
    }                  
</table>
```

This outputs:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
```

**Q:** How can I achieve:

```
value1    value2
value3    value4
value5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    @int amountOfItems = items.Count;
    for(int index = 0; index < amountOfItems; i++)
    {
       if(index % 2 == 0)
       {
         <tr>
            <td>
              @items[index].value
            </td>
       }
       else
       {
            <td>
              @items[index].value
            </td>
         </tr>
       }
    }
    @if(amountOfItems % 2 != 0)
    {
       </tr>
    }                  
</table>
```

**EDIT**: Using `foreach` and considering items is of type `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`

```
<table>
    @int amountOfItems = items.Count;
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
       int index = items.IndexOf(item);
       if(index % 2 == 0)
       {
         <tr>
            <td>
              @items[index].value
            </td>
       }
       else
       {
            <td>
              @items[index].value
            </td>
         </tr>
       }
    }
    @if(amountOfItems % 2 != 0)
    {
       </tr>
    }                  
</table>
```

Comment: @alex87 I've updated answer to include only `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

Hth...

```
<table>
    @{
        var count = mylist.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            <tr>                    
                <td>@mylist[i]</td>

                @*or (i & 1) == 0*@
                <td>@( (i % 2) == 0 ? i + 1 < count ? mylist[++i] : string.Empty : string.Empty)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```